# Web Api 2 controller to download wikipedia api and show json output on web

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, webclient

I am trying to parse a wikipedia api which contain the short text of an article.I am using ASP.Net MVC for coding. My wikipedia api is https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&explaintext&exintro&titles=Berlin&redirects= which is in json formatted. At present what I have done is - inside the Model I created a folder named Wiki, and inside it I created four class named Limits.cs, Pageval.cs, Query.cs, Rootobject.cs.

```
public class Limits
{
    public int extracts { get; set; }
}

public class Pageval
{
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string extract { get; set; }
}
 public class Query
{
    public Dictionary<string, Pageval> pages { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
    public Query query { get; set; }
    public Limits limits { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the controller class I created a WebApi 2 contrller to make the model object show on the web. In this case I am very new in handling this situation because I am new at MVC. I am trying to parse in this way but it is not working at all.

```
 public class WikiController : ApiController
  {
    // GET: api/Wiki


    // GET: api/Wiki/5
    public string GetShortText(string name)
    {

        string result;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            var response = client.DownloadString("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&explaintext&exintro&titles=" + name + "&redirects=");

            var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response);
            var firstKey = responseJson.query.pages.First().Key;
            var extract = responseJson.query.pages[firstKey].extract;

            try
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@".(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\)).(.)");
                string.Format("Before:{0}", extract);
                extract = regex.Replace(extract, string.Empty);
                string result1 = String.Format(extract);
                result = Regex.Replace(result1, @"\\n", " ");
            }


            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = "Error";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The Routconfig is-

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog: when I naviage to http://localhost:53423/api/wiki  It shows on web.                                                                                                  <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53423/api/wiki'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Wiki' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>  . But I want to see onlty extrated shortText

Comment: Add [Route("{name}")] to the top of your GetShortText method.

Comment: @nowmim21: Can you include your route config in your question?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog: I have edited and given my route config below my question.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog. Yes I have tried with your given url address, But the result is same as I mentioned in my previous answer. It is just not just showing the resulted short-text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things. You can use attribute routing or you can define a route for your custom method. The reason it does not map at the moment is that you do not have a route that defines your parameter. So going the route way you can define

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Wiki",
            url: "api/wiki/getshorttext/name",
            defaults: new { controller = "Wiki", action = "GetShortText", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        )
```

;

On a side note as you are performing a I/O bound operation I would suggest making your action `async` using `async and await` feature of .net. This way you won't block any thread while you waiting for Wikipedia to respond. Also `HttpClient` offers a `DownloadStringAsync` which is awaitable. Have a look at [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802603.aspx)

Comment: I have tried but it is showing HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. Where should I edit this code at routconfig.cs or in webapiconfig.cs

Comment: Which means now route should be valid. Check you security? Do the users have to log in etc.

Comment: Ok that's a separate issue.

Comment: You can post the login issue as a separate question. What is the error u getting at login.

Comment: But except login If I want to search it with localhost:53423/api/wiki by typing , this should show something on the web.I am not sure about coding also.Whether is it the proper way to get the json file or not. Because when I tried with sample value1 and value2 that time it shows string value 1 and value 2 on the web.

Comment: Try to go to localhost.../Api/wiki/getshorttext/somename

Comment: And make sure you editing api routes not Mvc routes. Should be in webapiconfig class or something.